# SQLite - Ordering

Tags: sqlite, sorting

I have a strange issue where upon selecting information from a SQLite database, ans ordering based upon date, the results returned are invalid.

My SQL statement is as such:

```
Select pk from usersDates order by datetime(usersDate, 'localtime') ASC
```

I have dates stored in the database which range as far as 2111. However the order the data is returned in indicates that dates from 2036 happen after the ones from 2111.
The column 'usersDate is actually a double (time interval since 1970 / unix time) - hence the reason for the cast.

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: Have you tried ordering without the cast to see if they're in the right order then?  Could it be that your 2036 dates are casting incorrectly?

Comment: If you take out the cast in the order by and it works, you could just leave the cast out.  Just cast when you actually want to display it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should re-read the [date and time syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). The `'localtime'` modifier expects an UTC time on its left.

Use `SELECT pk FROM usersDates ORDER BY datetime(usersDate, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') ASC`.

Comment: I'll add from my comment above here.  Isn't the cast just doing extra work for the system?  Ordering by your double should still provide the same order should it not?  Then you can just cast what you want to display.  Seems like it would be more efficient.

Comment: @wilbbe01: of course the cast is unnecessary if usersDate has integer type affinity. But this answer is to show what is unaccurate in OP query.

Comment: Yep, just pointing out to op that his query might best be fixed by removing the cast completely.